# Find the limiting distribution of the following random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, order-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ Be independent random variables with common density:

$$f_X(x)=\alpha x^{-(\alpha+1)}. x>1$$

Where $\alpha>0$.  Define a new sequence of random variables:

$$Y_n=(1/n^{1/\alpha})X_{(n)}$$

Where $X_{(n)}$ is the highest observation of n I.I.d. r.v. $X_1,…,X_n$.
Show that $Y_n$ converges in distribution as $n\to \infty$ and find the limiting distribution.

Comment: Please consider: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\Pr(Y_n\leq y)=\Pr(\max X_n\leq yn^{\frac 1\alpha})=\left(\Pr( X_1\leq yn^{\frac 1\alpha})\right)^n\\
=\left(\int_1^{yn^{\frac 1\alpha}} \alpha x^{-\alpha-1}dx\right)^n=\left(\frac{-1}{x^\alpha}\Bigg|_1^{yn^{\frac 1\alpha}}\right)^n=\left(1-\frac{1}{ny^\alpha}\right)^n.
$$

Comment: Thanks Arash I ended up getting $\lim{n\to\infty}F_Y(y)=exp(-1/y^{\alpha})$ does this sound right?

Comment: Seems correct to me!

Comment: Cheers man that one was bugging me!!